# Removing special characters in the beginning of a word in R

Tags: r, gsub

I am using the following code to remove the special characters from the begining of a word:

```
>gsub("^[^[:alnum:]]",'','#C++')
[1] "C++"
```

But If there are multiple special characters in the beggining it removes only the first one:

```
>gsub("^[^[:alnum:]]",'','$#C++')
[1] "#C++"
```

How can I make it to remove all the special characters in the begining so the output should be `"C++"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We match one or more non-alpha numeric characters (`[^[:alnum:]]+`) from the beginning of the string (`^`) and replace it with `''`.

```
 sub("^[^[:alnum:]]+",'','$#C++')
```

Or use

```
 sub("^\\W+",'','$#C++')
 #[1] "C++"
```