# how to remove special character from the beginning of a string in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove all the special characters like {@,<,!,\,",#,$,%,/,(,),=,?,',¿,`,^,´,:,.,-,} from the beginning of the word or from the end of the word. for example:

```
    emails              email
    `xxxx@gmail.com     xxxx@gmail.com
    ^bbb@yahool.com     bbb@yahool.com
    hjhk@grk.co!        hjhk@grk.co
    $gh$hd@test.co       gh$hd@test.co
    good_email@test.co  good_email@test.co
    gggh@gh.tom)        gggh@gh.tom
```

Here the first column "emails" is the actual column and the last column "email" is the desired output. Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156898/removing-special-characters-in-the-beginning-of-a-word-in-r?rq=1  The "not alphanumeric at the start of the string" seems to be the key part.

Comment: You can use a RFC5322 regex to clean the edges.  https://regex101.com/r/wDPJ64/1/

Comment: If you change your title to specify _EMAILS_, I'll open this back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex and remove it with empty string,

```
^\W+|\W+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cNFWCM/1)**

**[R Code demo](https://rextester.com/XIFZH94025)**

```
gsub("^\\W+|\\W+$", "", "`xxxx@gmail.com")
gsub("^\\W+|\\W+$", "", "^bbb@yahool.com")
gsub("^\\W+|\\W+$", "", "hjhk@grk.co!")
gsub("^\\W+|\\W+$", "", "$gh$hd@test.co")
gsub("^\\W+|\\W+$", "", "good_email@test.co")
gsub("^\\W+|\\W+$", "", "gggh@gh.tom)")
```

Prints cleaned email addresses,

```
[1] "xxxx@gmail.com"
[1] "bbb@yahool.com"
[1] "hjhk@grk.co"
[1] "gh$hd@test.co"
[1] "good_email@test.co"
[1] "gggh@gh.tom"
```

Comment: Given `x <- c("\`xxxx@gmail.com", "^bbb@yahool.com", "hjhk@grk.co!", "$gh$hd@test.co", "good_email@test.co", "gggh@gh.tom)")` you may use `sapply` instead of typing `gsub` six times: `sapply(x, function(i) gsub("^\\W+|\\W+$", "", i), USE.NAMES = FALSE)` (Sorry if you know that, but you do not seem to be a R user.) (+1)

Comment: @markus: I will honestly accept and yes you guessed it right, I am completely noob in R. Though trying to learn it through regular expressions. Thank you for the pointers and suggestions in your comment. I'll surely look into it. Thanks again, and I appreciate and Thanks for upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/LcdCtu/1) might help you to get your desired chars instead of removing other chars. It would create a group, where you can simply call it using `$1`.

```
([A-Za-z0-9\._\-\@]+)
```

[image]

It is usually safe to have a limited list of chars to pass, and filter every other chars.

Comment: What question are you answering?