# Removing the "$" from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a 10 x ~15,000 data frame with salaries in column 9 and I'm trying to remove the $ from the start of each entry in that column.

This is the best version of what I have. I am new to R and far more familiar with other languages. Preferably if there is a way to run an operation on each element of a data frame (like cellfun in Matlab, or a list comprehension in python) that would make this far easier.
Based on my debugging attempts it seems like gsub just isn't doing anything, even outside a loop. Any suggestions from a more experienced user would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
bbdat <- read.csv("C:/Users/musta/Downloads/BBs1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
i <- 0
for (val in bbdat[,9])
{
  i = i+1
  bbdat[i,9]<- gsub("$","",val)
}
```

Comment: `gsub` is vectorized.  you need `gsub("$", "", bbdat[,9], fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34156898/5325862) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37471921/5325862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is a metacharacter and it implies the end of the string.  If we want to evaluate it literally, either use the `fixed = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`) or keep it inside square bracket (`"[$]"`) or escape (`\\$`).  As `gsub/sub` are vectorized, looping is not required

```
bbdat[,9] <- gsub("$", "", bbdat[,9], fixed = TRUE)
```

If there is only a single instance of `$` in each element, use `sub` (`gsub - global substitution) instead of`gsub`

Comment: Ah, thank you I had a feeling there was an easier way to do this since it's so simple in every other language. Thank you for your help